# ExcludeFromCodeCoverage not working for CloseAsync method

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-coverage, mstest, azure-eventhub

I know this question has been asked before too, but I couldn't find any solution for this problem.

I have a Microsoft Azure Event hubs processor, `ProcessorHost` which is implementing `IEventProcessor` interface.

It has methods `IEventProcessor.OpenAsync`, `IEventProcessor.CloseAsync` and few other custom methods in this class. For those custom methods I have written the test cases using MSTest and they have passed.

Now I have decorated `OpenAsync` and `CloseAsync` methods with `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` like mentioned below.

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
async Task IEventProcessor.CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
{

}

[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
Task IEventProcessor.OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
{

}
```

I'm using Sonar-cube to test the code coverage. When I run the report to see the code coverage, it shows that `OpenAsync` method is covered, but `CloseAsync` method is not covered even after decorating with `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]`.

So I want to know is there anything else which has to be done for CloseAsync method to exclude it from code coverage.

**EDIT :**
The complete method of closeAsync

```
async Task IEventProcessor.CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
{                
    if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown)
    {
        await context.CheckpointAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity Have you tried decorating whole class?

Comment: @MihirDave Yes, I have tried. It has excluded the whole class and code coverage showed as 100%. The problem is when I'm decorating individual methods. Also , it has problem only for CloseAsync method. For rest all methods are working fine as expected.

Comment: @CrazyCoder just for trouble shooting have you investigated if it could be because of the `async Task`? See if you can refactor the method to just return `Task` to see if the hypothesis is sound.

Comment: @Nkosi I have tried to refactor my code, but couldn't do it. I have edited my question to add complete code of the method. If anyone could help me refactor it, it would be great.Thanks!

Comment: @CrazyCoder I meant for now just return a completed task and remove the async and await to see if the method would then be included. If it is them we can see about refactoring the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if removing the *async / await* helps.

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
Task IEventProcessor.CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)  
    if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown) {
        return context.CheckpointAsync();
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

It is the only noticeable difference between the implementations of the two methods

Comment: Yes, I have tried this and it worked. But I want to know if this the right way to do it. I mean, if we change the code for the purpose of test cases, will it effect the actual working of the application. I will anyways test, but just wanted to know if there is any problem by changing like this.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Changing the code like this will not affect how it worked before. there is no problem by changing like this. This works just as the previous code. Just a different syntax. The problem appears to be with the `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` not recognizing `async` Tasks. Could be a framework issue and would suggest raising it with the maintainers of the code.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a bug in SonarC# related with this attribute. Please check this: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/1421

Try to update to the latest version of SonarQube.

Comment: I was using Sonarqube 7.1 . But now I have tried with 7.2 community version as well. Still the same problem.